# Unable to list directory of downloaded files

Tags: file, download

new to using Tensorflow. I'm making an image classifier and downloaded Simpsons characters images from Google. Using Colab to run my code. Can't seem to access file! This is my code:

```
!wget -qq https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gc4fr1uiveedn6/simpsons.zip?dl=0
!unzip -qq simpsons.zip?dl=0
!rm simpsons.zip?dl=0
!ls simpsons
!ls simpsons/homer
```

Output from !ls simpsons is:
'bart '  'homer '  'lisa '  'maggie '  'marge '

Output from !ls simpsons/homer is:
ls: cannot access 'simpsons/homer': No such file or directory

I've done ls/simpsons/'homer' but still getting errors and not sure why...
Any advise please?

Answer (score 0):

There is a whitespace `'simpsons/homer '` when I tried it. But this isn't a tensorflow programming question at all.

```
# !wget -qq https://www.dropbox.com/s/9gc4fr1uiveedn6/simpsons.zip?dl=0
# !unzip -qq simpsons.zip?dl=0
# !rm simpsons.zip?dl=0
# !ls simpsons
# !ls simpsons/homer
!ls 'simpsons/homer '

homer_001.jpg  homer_017.jpg  homer_033.jpg  homer_049.jpg  homer_065.jpg
homer_002.jpg  homer_018.jpg  homer_034.jpg  homer_050.jpg  homer_066.jpg
homer_003.jpg  homer_019.jpg  homer_035.jpg  homer_051.jpg  homer_067.jpg
homer_004.jpg  homer_020.jpg  homer_036.jpg  homer_052.jpg  homer_068.jpg
..........
```

Comment: Hello- thanks so much for this! I'd tried simpsons/'homer ' and that hadn't worked and was confused. Point about not tf noted. Apologies. I should have put this under command line/colab perhaps. Thanks your assistance.